# Error in v-on handler TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__babel_runtime_helpers_typeof___default.a.convert is not a function

Tags: vue.js, jspdf

I'm trying to export and html to a pdf in vue project (2.5.11) with jspdf plugin (2.5.1)

But when I call the function jspdf.html appears an error on the console:

```
Error in v-on handler TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__babel_runtime_helpers_typeof___default.a.convert is not a function
```

But if I use jspdf.html2canvas() it works

Here a piece of my code

```
onClickPrintReport() {
        // Editor
        const doc = new jsPDF({
            orientation: 'l',
        });
        let ncToPrint = this.$refs.ncPrint.innerHTML,
            pdfWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.width - 20,
            sanitizedContent;

        window.html2canvas = html2canvas;
        sanitizedContent = DOMPurify.sanitize(ncToPrint);

        doc.html(sanitizedContent, {
            callback: (doc) => {
                window.open(doc.output('bloburl'), '_blank').focus();
            },
            html2canvas: {
                width: pdfWidth,
            },
            margin: [0, 0, 10, 0],
            width: pdfWidth,
            windowWidth: pdfWidth,
            autoPaging: 'text',
            x: 10,
            y: 20,
        });
    },
```

I had try to downgrade jspdf version to 1.5 and jspdf.html works, but I cannot configure the output options and have a wrong format view.

Here my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@tinymce/tinymce-vue": "^3.2.8",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "html2canvas": "^1.4.1",
    "isomorphic-dompurify": "^1.8.0",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "prettier-eslint": "^13.0.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "v-clipboard": "^2.2.3",
    "vue": "^2.5.11",
    "vue-bootstrap-typeahead": "^0.2.6",
    "vue-directive-tooltip": "^1.6.3",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.24.4",
    "vue-resource": "^1.5.3",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.1",
    "vue-textarea-autosize": "^1.1.1",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2"
},
"browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
],
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "eslint": "^8.20.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.7.1",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.0",
    "vue-loader": "^13.0.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.4",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1"
}
```

Any help?

Thanks in advance